# Can´t call Firestore in Function

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I want to add Data to Firstore from Angular. I have initialized the Firestore Object in the Constructor.

```
constructor(angularFirestore: AngularFirestore){}
```

If I call this code inside the Constructor, it works for me.

```
  angularFirestore.collection("contactform").add({
    name: "test", message: "markb", subject: "test", email: "test"
  })
```

Now I want to call the function from my html, every time I clicked on the submit button.

```
 <form (submit)="addData()">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" id="nameLabel" for="name"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" tabindex="1">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" id="emailLabel" for="email"></label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" tabindex="2">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" id="subjectLabel" for="sublect"></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" tabindex="3">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" id="messageLabel" for="message"></label>
                    <textarea rows="6" cols="60" name="message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your message" tabindex="4"></textarea>                                 
                </div>

                <div class="text-center margin-top-25">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mod btn-border btn-large" >Send Message</button>
                </div>

            </form>
```

The function will be called, but no data is in the database. How can I fix this??

```
angularFirestore: AngularFirestore | any

public addData(){
  
  this.angularFirestore.collection("contactform").add({
    name: "test", message: "markb", subject: "test", email: "test"
  })
  
}
```

I have to declaire the angularFirestore there a second time, because otherwise i can´t call it. Thank you for any help and merry christmas!!

I eppected it will add the data to the database

Comment: Is it not possible to use html form and angular in one? If I use both, it does not work for me ..

Comment: Have you tried these two stackoverflow threads? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110905/adding-data-to-firebase-cloud-firestore-and-angular) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71260112/how-to-create-set-data-to-firestore-using-angularfire)

Comment: I solved my issue by my own. See the answear below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form and form name makes problems in Angular. In PHP it is essential but here not.

My HTML look like this:

> ```
> <div class="form-group">
>                 <label class="form-label" id="nameLabel" for="name"></label>
>                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  placeholder="Your name" tabindex="1">
>             </div>
>
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label class="form-label" id="emailLabel" for="email"></label>
>                 <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"  placeholder="Your Email" tabindex="2">
>             </div>
>
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label class="form-label" id="subjectLabel" for="sublect"></label>
>                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject"  placeholder="Subject" tabindex="3">
>             </div>
>
>             <div class="form-group">
>                 <label class="form-label" id="messageLabel" for="message"></label>
>                 <textarea rows="6" cols="60"  class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your message" tabindex="4"></textarea>      
>
>             </div>
>
>             <div class="text-center margin-top-25">
>                 <button  (click)="createData()">click me</button>
>             </div> <div>
> ```

The Typescript looks like this:

```
    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore){

}

public createData(){ 
  console.log("called")
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => { 
     this.firestore
         .collection("contactform")
         .add(
          {
            name: "555", message: "mark", subject: "test", email: "test"
          }
         )
         .then(
             res => {}, 
             err => reject(err)
         )
  }
)}
```